# Create a "podcast" tag?

Tags: discussion, tags

Many Dharma talks are available by podcast, as well as a number of podcasts on Buddhism in iTunes--would it be worthwhile to create a "podcast" tag?

Comment: Would the media tag cover it?

Comment: Let me examine that tag and get back to you :-)